# jenkins copy secret file to workspace - Tried other solutions but dint work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have uploaded .env file into my Jenkins Credentials and then created a pipeline (mentioned below).

Jenkins file content

```
    pipeline {
        agent any
        environment {
            /* Define any ENV variables */
            SECRET_FILE_IDS = credentials('FlaskCredId')
        }
        stages {
            stage("Clone repository") {
                steps {
                    checkout scm
                    sh "echo ${SECRET_FILE_IDS}"
                    sh "echo ${SECRET_FILE_IDS} > \"/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test/.env\" "
            }
        }
 
    }
```

I am trying to copy the uploaded `.env` file to my workspace(project directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test/.env), file is getting created but the content is rubbish.

Output file content as follows

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test@tmp/secretFiles/3c670c98-c7a1-4a76-b839-9299bc2d017b/.env
```

**Updating question**

I have even tried copying the file to the workplace using this line but it gives error.

```
sh "cp ${SECRET_FILE_IDS} \"/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test/\" "
```

**Error**

````
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [SECRET_FILE_IDS]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ cp **** /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test/
cp: cannot stat 'API': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Test@tmp/secretFiles/4ad9e8d4-ab6f-4ae4-8040-288b51dc5797/.env': No such file or directory```
````

Comment: I think the variable `SECRET_FILE_IDS` contains a path to a (temporary) secret file. You could copy it to the workspace from there.

Comment: I have tried that as well but I am getting another error,
```Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
   Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [SECRET_FILE_IDS]
   See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ cp **** /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Flask API Test/
cp: cannot stat 'API': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Test@tmp/secretFiles/4ad9e8d4-ab6f-4ae4-8040-288b51dc5797/.env': No such file or directory```